# Знак препинания после слова "оказалось"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп

1. *Оказалось ( ) нет там ничего полезного.*
2. *Думал, можно написать по-быстрому и прокатит. Оказалось ( ) нет.*

Я бы поставил тире, так как вторая часть бессоюзного предложения имеет изъяснительное значение (перед ней можно вставить союз что), причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта. Но вот сомневаюсь: может, и запятая сгодится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае надо ставить запятую, выделяя вводное слово.

Во втором случае — тире. Тут пропущен союз.

Comment: Предлог? Вроде: На нет и суда нет?

Comment: @shampar, союз. Исправил ответ. Спасибо за комментарий.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Оказалось, нет там ничего полезного.**
   Это простое предложение; вводное слово *оказалось* (односоставное безличное вводное предложение) можно опустить.

*Оказалось, судить анимационное кино труднее, чем игровые фильмы.*
Из интервью с И. Муравьевой

*Оказалось, она прилетела сюда со своих золотых россыпей на самолете.*
М. М. Пришвин. Серая Сова

2. **Оказалось, нет.**
   Это тоже простое предложение, имеющее смысл "оказалось, не прокатит" или "оказалось, не прокатило".

Мне кажется, что в обоих случаях можно обойтись запятыми.
Тире обычно используется в конструкциях с союзом:

*Когда-то я так думала

По молодости лет.

Казалось, это главное,

А оказалось — нет.*
Е. Горбовская. Я думала, что главное...

Answer (score 0):

**1. Что интересно!**

Вот **[Справочник по пунктуации](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/okazyvaetsya)**

**Как оказалось / оказывается**, вводное слово

```
Подробно о пунктуации при вводных словах и сочетаниях см. в 
Прил. 2.

При нем же, как оказалось, была и моя квартирка, 
показавшаяся мне роскошной. Б. Окуджава, Свидание с 
Бонапартом. Образ же человека, как оказывается, – больше 
человека. Б. Пастернак, Охранная грамота.
! Не смешивать с сочетанием наречия «как» и вводного слова 
«оказывается».«Вот как, оказывается, сходят с ума!» – 
подумал он и ухватился за притолоку. М. Булгаков, Мастер и 
Маргарита.
```

**Примечание**. Не будем считать ***оказалось*** вводным словом (нет союза ***КАК***), если это не вводное слово. И не будем ничего "опускать" и считать сложное предложение простым. Во всем нужна **ТОЧНОСТЬ.** С точностью **до слова.**

**РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ**

(1) ***ОказАлось**, // нет там / ничего полЕзного.*

Это **БСП**, бессоюзная связь, отношения изъяснительные. Первое предложение безличное.
Ставится **запятая**, нет подчеркнутой паузы. Основное содержание во второй части, а первая часть по семантике близка к вводному предложению.

(2) *Думал, можно написать по-быстрому и прокатит. **ОказАлось** — нЕт.*

Здесь **также БСП**, изъяснительные отношения обозначены **тире**, делается подчеркнутая пауза. Причина — разная структура двух частей.